# Where is source code of ONLYOFFICE Documents for Android located?

Tags: onlyoffice

I am not sure this part is open source actually.
I searched [the ONLYOFFICE GitHub repositories](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE) but do not find anything relevant.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments on [this blog post](https://www.onlyoffice.com/blog/2018/06/stable-version-of-onlyoffice-documents-2-0-for-android-is-released/) the Android app is free but the source has not been opened.

[image: comments]